# What is Ingest Controller?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, bulkinsert, data-extraction

My colleague wrote that Stored procedure that generates report is ready, but the ingest controller is not ready yet.

what does Ingest Controller mean?

Little background here:

We are getting excel source file and loading it to SQL Server to generate report of it.

My understanding that he is referring to SSIS Package that would load the data to SQL Server or just SQL bulk insert statement, but less probable...

Comment: Ingest Controller is not a term used in SQL Server. This is most likely a term used in your organisation.

Comment: You should be asking your colleague this question.